# Create a password application. How to end loop after password is entered wrong 3 times

Tags: java, loops

I'm a beginner programmer taking IB Computer Science and am studying from the textbook doing the exercises. How do I end this loop after the user has incorrectly entered the password 3 times.

```
public class Password
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int remaining = 3;
        String reenter="hello";
        do
        {

            String password=IBIO.inputString("Please enter the password: ");
            if (password.indexOf("hello")>-1)
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Access Denied");
                remaining--;
            }
           reenter=IBIO.inputString("Enter the password: ");

        }
        while (reenter.equals("hello"));
        while (remaining > 0);
    }
}
```

So this is what it looks like now but as I enter the password wrong it only says access denied once then kind of fail to show anything. I'm pretty sure I can't have 2 whiles above each other like that. And also when I input the password correctly it keeps asking me to input the password so it doesn't close the loop. And only every other time I input it correctly does it say "Welcome"

Comment: So you are aware, this is not a strong or proper authentication scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Introdcue a counter

```
int remaining = 3;
```

and decrement it in the `else` branch:

```
remaining--
```

Check for it being larger than 0. Replace the line

```
while (reenter.equals("hello"));
```

with this:

```
while (remaining > 0);
```

Comment: It is more efficient to use `while (remaining != 0)`, because there are less machine code instructions.

Comment: @zmirc Well, the problem looks simple enough to not care about a machine code instruction or two. Let's be generous.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable and increment it each time user inputs password. When it's done three times you can exit from method.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while (reenter.equals("hello"));
while (remaining > 0);
```

with

```
while (reenter.equals("hello") && remaining > 0);
```

then

```
 if (remaining > 0)
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    else
        System.out.println("You are banned");
```